# Wireless router for mac, pc, linux and learning

Tags: wireless-router

I have a macbook pro, some old windows laptops, some of which I plan to put linux on, mostly to play around with.  I'd like to get a wireless router to use with all of these and maybe also to try fiddling with the firmware.  I don't know anything about them yet, I'm not sure what to look for in a router, esp. one that's open but will work with all these different wireless cards.  Any suggestions on routers or what specifically to focus my research on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WiFi is an industry standard, so all your devices should play nice. Get with with a/b/g/n though because n is blazing fast. To look for a specific router, I would check DDWRT's [list of compatible hardware](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Supported_Devices) (and since most firmware hacks theoretically has the same bootstrap codebase, a DDWRT compatible router should work for more than one firmware).

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @digitxp, but you should also consider the excellent [AirPort Extreme](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002TLTG9E) for its USB connection that shares any external hard drive or zero-conf (Bonjour) printer wirelessly. It can't be loaded with DD-WRT, but has most of the common features that people look for in DD-WRT, plus it does a/b/g/n and can broadcast two wireless networks simultaneously.